# what's the meaning of "over the strain of"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Signs that ISIS may be fracturing in some local areas **over the strain
>   of** attempting to function as a state. -CNN Student News

what's the meaning of **"over the strain of"**? 
I looked up in the dictionary, but I couldn't find this phrase.

Comment: Read it as "due to the strain", where "strain" means stretching, possibly stretching to a point where the item would break.

Comment: Here, "over" = "as a result of," and "the strain of" = "the burden of."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the phrase here is referring to bearing weight, like the legs of a table or chair. It's primarily used to great but eventually useless effort or stress. The article was saying it's too much for them to handle.

Comment: This may have the makings of a good answer, but please consider adding references and definitions to support your suggestion. For instance, you might clarify the difference between *stress* and *strain*.

Answer (score 1):

*Over* as a preposition has the following meaning in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/over):

> Above, implying superiority after a contest; in spite of;
>   notwithstanding.

We triumphed over difficulties. The bill was passed over the veto. It was a fine victory over their opponents.

*Over the strain of ...* means *in spite of the strain of ....*

Comment: No, pretty much the opposite.  *Over* here means about, concerning, or in connection with.  The fracturing is because of the strain of operating as a state.

Comment: @deadrat You can google this and see how it was used and compare it with the sentence in question, "She kept up with traffic because she had no choice but to do the same. ... She shouted to be heard over the strain of Hermes' engine. “I'm in trouble. A black SUV is trying to run me off the road—” She barely had the last word out when the SUV ..."

Comment: @deadrat If some of ISIS factions want to become independent of ISIS because they don't share the same view or strategy, those factions should overcome the strain of ISIS' attempt to function as a state. It is an obstacle, not a cause.

Comment: Her shouting "over the strain of Hermes' engine" means raising her voice above the noise of an over-taxed engine.  This is a sense of *over* meaning higher in some sense.  It has nothing to do with the OP's quote.

Comment: I have googled it and found it here: http://www.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1503/11/sn.01.html, where in the words of CNN reporter Starr:  "Signs that ISIS may be fracturing in some local areas over the strain of attempting to function as a state.... ISIS having trouble providing basic municipal services."  In other words, as long as ISIS was strictly a military operation, it held together.  When it tries to govern, the difficulties (i.e., strains) may break it up.

Comment: @deadrat That's exactly what I mean. "Over" is not always used for raising something over a "physical/concrete position" as in the case of the noise. It is also used for "positions abstract/unseen. ISIS is sitting higher than those factions. Then, what's the difference?

Comment: Again, *over* in the OP has nothing to do with its other meaning of "above."  It means "about" in that context.  ISIS isn't sitting "higher" than "those factions," whatever that means.  ISIS is supposedly coming unglued because it can't figure out how to govern the areas it has conquered.

Comment: @deadrat It has nothing to do with *municipal services or a military operation*. You are overthinking this. Those factions have been constrained by ISIS to become part of the State. And in spite of the constraint, some factions are beginning to break away from ISIS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30134/discussion-between-deadrat-and-rathony).

Comment: @deadrat I was talking about ISIS rules those factions insisting they should obey it as if it was the central government. That's higher position. The federal government is sitting higher than the state government. Never mind. I know where you are coming from with this. I am pretty sure you know where I am coming from. I don't see it is *that* necessary to continue this discussion.

Comment: Never mind, eh?  Imagine my surprise.  WS2 is right; your interpretation is wrong and misleading.  Understand that or don't; fix it or not.  It's up to you.

Comment: You don't want to hear that you're wrong when you're absolutely sure you're right.  Again, imagine my surprise.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance I think ***over*** is being used in the same sense as *they had an argument over money*. That is, it is another word for *about*, and explains what it is that is causing the fracturing.

I do not happen to think that it makes for very good syntax and would have been more inclined, myself, to have used *under*. Although it does make for a slightly different nuance in meaning.

*Signs that ISIS may be fracturing in some areas, **under** the strain of trying to operate as a state*

***Over*** tries to explain what is causing the fracturing, ***under*** explains the circumstances in which it is happening.

Comment: It was my initial thought.